# How to convert CSV to JSON without JSONArray?

Tags: json, csv, converters

I have a CSV that looks like this (below is the header column and one sample row).

```
UID MSA Latitude Longitude
1   New York-Newark-Jersey City, NY-NJ-PA   40.7127837  -74.0059413
```

I want to convert this to a JSON. Sites like [this](http://www.csvjson.com/csv2json) don't work for me because they convert it to an array of JSONs. Instead, what I want is a series of JSON objects that are titled by the UID. That would look like the below (pretend the second object has different data than the first).

```
[
"1" : {
"Latitude" : 40.7127837,
"Longitude" : -74.0059413,
"MSA" : "New York-Newark-Jersey City, NY-NJ-PA"
},
 "2" : {
"Latitude" : 40.7127837,
"Longitude" : -74.0059413,
"MSA" : "New York-Newark-Jersey City, NY-NJ-PA"
}
]
```

Is there a tool out there that can do this for me? I can write a script that would do it but I don't want to.

Comment: A scripting language like Perl is the tool you are looking for. There's a limit to how much flexibility you can put into a text conversion utility before it effectively turns into a programming language.,

Comment: Is there any reason you mention Perl specifically? Would Python, F# etc etc work equally well?

Comment: I happen to know Perl. I don't do much of that kind of processing so I couldn't tell you which languages are best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

If `filter.jq` contains the following filter

```
def parse:
  [
      split("\n")[]           # split string into lines
    | split("\t")             # split into columns
    | select(length>0)        # eliminate blanks
  ]
;
def makeobj($headers;$data):
  [                           # e.g.
      [$headers, $data]       # [["MSA","LATITUDE","LONGITUDE"],["Savannah, GA"...
    | transpose[]             # ["MSA","Savannah, GA"], ["LATITUDE","32.0835"] ...
    | {key:.[0], value:.[1]}  # {"key":"MSA","value":"Savannah, GA"} ...
  ] | from_entries            # {"MSA":"Savannah, GA","LATITUDE":"32.0835",...
  | .LATITUDE  |= tonumber
  | .LONGITUDE |= tonumber
;
def reorganize:
    .[0] as $h                # save headers
  | reduce .[1:][] as $r (    # construct final object result
    {}
    ; .[$r[0]] = makeobj($h[1:]; $r[1:])
    )
;
parse | reorganize
```

and `data` contains tab-separated

```
UID MSA LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
1   New York-Newark-Jersey City, NY-NJ-PA   40.7127837  -74.0059413
2   Seattle, WA 47.6062 122.3321
3   San Francisco, CA   37.7749 122.4194
4   Savannah, GA    32.0835 81.0998
```

then the command

```
$ jq -M -Rsr -f filter.jq data
```

produces

```
{
  "1": {
    "MSA": "New York-Newark-Jersey City, NY-NJ-PA",
    "LATITUDE": 40.7127837,
    "LONGITUDE": -74.0059413
  },
  "2": {
    "MSA": "Seattle, WA",
    "LATITUDE": 47.6062,
    "LONGITUDE": 122.3321
  },
  "3": {
    "MSA": "San Francisco, CA",
    "LATITUDE": 37.7749,
    "LONGITUDE": 122.4194
  },
  "4": {
    "MSA": "Savannah, GA",
    "LATITUDE": 32.0835,
    "LONGITUDE": 81.0998
  }
}
```

Comment: I've already solved my problem but marked this as correct for others with the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't suggest you are looking for a way to automate this process.

[This site](https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/) may provide what you are looking for.  You will need to select JSON-Dictionary for your output format.

```
UID MSA LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
1   New York-Newark-Jersey City, NY-NJ-PA   40.7127837  -74.0059413
2   Seattle, WA 47.6062 122.3321
3   San Francisco, CA   37.7749 122.4194
4   Savannah, GA    32.0835 81.0998


Output:
{
  "1": { "MSA":"New York-Newark-Jersey City, NY-NJ-PA", "LATITUDE":40.7127837, "LONGITUDE":-74.0059413},
  "2": { "MSA":"Seattle, WA", "LATITUDE":47.6062, "LONGITUDE":122.3321},
  "3": { "MSA":"San Francisco, CA", "LATITUDE":37.7749, "LONGITUDE":122.4194},
  "4": { "MSA":"Savannah, GA", "LATITUDE":32.0835, "LONGITUDE":81.0998}
}
```

You can download here: [test.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0kVXmFI_3oAQklQMllQSnhyLVk/view?usp=sharing) which I used to test.

Comment: Nice touch looking up some other cities.

Comment: Thaks, it's the OCD in me I guess.